# Create a .txt file with header

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a text file with header.

Currently i'm using `StreamWriter` to create the txt file if it's not available, but I need a header to be written in only once, as everytime I call this method I would write a new line into the .txt file

Below is my code:

```
string line = userID + "\t" + fullname + "\t" + module + "\t" +
              datetime + "\t" + SQLStatement;

string fileExcel, filePath, fileName;
fileExcel = "Audit.txt";
filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
fileName = filePath + "\\" + fileExcel;
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true);

file.WriteLine(line);
file.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Boolean writeHeader = (!File.Exists(fileName));

using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
{
    if (writeHeader)
    {
       file.WriteLine(headerLine);
    }

    file.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: You should really be wrapping disposables up in a [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx) block.

Comment: @James you don't have to when calling [`StreamWriter.Close()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx), it disposes the underlying stream. But allright.

Comment: what happens if there is an exception *before* you get to call `file.Close()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster You should always call 'Dispose' on an object that implements the IDispose interface even if you know the current implementation only calls another method like 'Close' because the implementation can change in future versions causing easily avoidable issues.